# Render INSERT INTO SELECT RETURNING using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm really trying to grok SQLAlchemy, but it's going slowly and confusingly. I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO
    user (name, email)
SELECT
    :name, :email
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM other WHERE other.id > :some_id
)
RETURNING id
```

and I want to run this through SQLAlchemy in a more pythonic way than just supplying raw SQL to execute.

I can't figure out which functions exist on which objects - `filter`, `where`, `insert`, `add`... the documentation is so verbose and overwhelming, I get lost.

I've got `user` objects that get generated and are waiting to be added to the database - this is the query that should be doing it, if someone can help me figure out how to construct this.

I'd like this to all be in one query because there is a race condition, where sometimes I get a new `other` object, which invalidates the current `user` objects and so I no longer want to add them.

Comment: Have you defined `Table` or declarative (ORM) classes? In other words are you trying to use the Core or the ORM – SQLAlchemy is sort of 2 libraries in one.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, this is a conditional insert if the record of a name,email pair is not already in the user table?

Comment: @IljaEverilä - I think that's where I get confused, the 2 libraries in 1 aspect. We've got lots of classes that inherit from `Base` which uses `declarative_base`, but nothing that inherits from `Table` (further complicating my sifting through the documentation). Typical db interactions call things like `session.add(some_obj)` - so I think that's ORM?

Comment: Yep, that's the ORM at play. Note that the 2 are not entirely separate, and the ORM is built on top of Core, so they play very well together. The 2 tutorials on [Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) and [ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) could be a good read for forming a mental image of what is what. For example you don't inherit from Table, but use Table objects themselves, if need be.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to render your query with [SQLAlchemy-Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/). I'll provide examples for simple `Table` objects and for models using `declarative_base`.

Given this demostration code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import table, column, Unicode, String, Integer

user = table(
    'user',
    column('id', Integer),
    column('name', Unicode),
    column('email', String),
)

other = table(
    'other',
    column('id', Integer),
    column('name', Unicode),
    column('email', String),
)
```

If you use the ORM then your definitions probably look like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Unicode, String


Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', Unicode)
    email = Column('email', String)


class Other(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'other'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', Unicode)
    email = Column('email', String)

# Pull out the `Table` objects from the mapped models.
user = User.__table__
other = Other.__table__
```

Given this, you can render the query like such:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, literal, exists, text

# Your inputs.
name = 'foo'
email = 'foo@example.com'
other_id = 1

# Compile the query for demonstration purposes
print(
    user
    .insert()
    .from_select(
        ['name', 'email'],
        select(
            [literal(name),
             literal(email)])
        .where(~exists([other.c.id])
               .where(other.c.id > other_id))
    )
    .returning(text('id'))
)
```

Compiling the query will give you the following SQL string:

```sql
INSERT INTO "user" (name, email) SELECT :param_1 AS anon_1, :param_2 AS anon_2 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT other.id 
FROM other 
WHERE other.id > :id_1)) RETURNING id
```

Comment: What if I've got `declarative_base`s instead of `table` classes running around? Sorry for not making that clearer earlier on; this looks like a solid path to get me started though

Comment: A minor nit, but the collection of columns to the light weight `table()` construct is expected to be [`column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) constructs, or so it is [documented](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.table.params.columns).

Comment: @dwanderson You can get the `Table` objects from mapped classes by doing `Foo.__table__`.